# Tablet App with titanium appcelerator?

Tags: android, screen, resolution, tablet

I want to develop Android app with titanium appcelerator which will support for Phones and Tablets .I am putting `anyDencity='false'` in `Tiapp.xml` it is working for all phones but when I run the app in Tablet the UI is not fit.So, Do I have to write separate code for tablet or is there any setting?

I am giving like this:

```
 <sdk-version>3.1.2.GA</sdk-version>
    <android xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
        <tool-api-level>8</tool-api-level>
        <manifest android:versionCode="1" android:versionName="1.0" package="com.apw.cinemark">
            <supports-screens android:anyDensity="false"/>

            <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" android:targetSdkVersion="16"/>
        </manifest>
    </android>
```

in Tiapp.xml please see and let me know further details. Thanks in Advance....

Comment: could you run the same titanium code on both android device and android tablet?

Answer (score 1):

As an Android and Titanium developer, I would recommend you to writte your app in native Android, it makes it a lot easier to fit your screen configurations as you can set different xml views to each screen configuration.

With Titanium this is a little more tricky. In my Titanium app I always use calculated layouts using % width, but if you want a really different UI for tablet apps (i think that's better), i would develope two apps, one for phones and another for tablet.

My Titanium app runs OK on both tablet and phone, allways with caculated layouts.

Comment: I worked on native it is fine in my app i never used the Fragments so cal i run one app for diffrent devices ?